# Flash not supported on webapps

Tags: flash, webapps

On Ubuntu 14.04, you cannot see flash contents using a webapp such as youtube or grooveshark.

I installed flashplugin-istaller and pepperflashplugin-nonfree and I can see flash contents on both firefox and chromium

Comment: I wander whether it even makes sense - to run the Flash there e.g. Grooveshark has an HTML5 version too. Perhaps it is rather a problem with these webapps - the descriptors for the unity-webapps runner should feed it with the HTML5 version URL ....

Comment: i have the same problem. i put a bug on landscape https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-webapps-youtube/+bug/1310381

Comment: @Emilio Navarrete Lineros - thank you, I added myself to the bug affected users counter.

Comment: @Radu Rădeanu: I understand webapps are using 'Ubuntu Web Browser' and not Chromium or Firefox or whatever is the default browser

Comment: It's all about the [Bug #1308842](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-webapps-youtube/+bug/1308842). For the moment, you should use other alternatives to webapps, because *Oxide is adding support for pepper plugins, should be available shortly* (comment [#4](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-webapps-youtube/+bug/1308842/comments/40)).

Answer (score 1):

For Youtube, search for "Browser" in Dash and open https://www.youtube.com/html5 then press "Request for HTML5 player".

For Grooveshark the only way is to change link "http://grooveshark.com/" with "http://html5.grooveshark.com/" in grooveshark.user.js file located in "/usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-grooveshark"

P.S. I don't really understand why do you need to use webapp, but most of the functions are not gonna work anyway, until webapps will be fixed (not particular webapp, but webapp system).