# Ubuntu 14.04 Youtube app not working

Tags: software-center, flash, youtube

I installed the youtube app (unity-webapps-youtube) from ubuntu software center. But it tells me it cannot play any videos because of a missing flash player. Flash plays fine in either Firefox or Google Chrome but not in the app. Is there any workaround? Something like telling the app to use html5 instead of flash for example?

Comment: please give me the outputs: `dpkg -l | grep minitube` & `dpkg -l | grep ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: @Haifi, which app are you talking about precisely? There are a few different youtube apps in the repos. What is the precise error message?

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish AFAIK minitube doesn't require Flash.

Comment: Its not minitube, its the webapp. In top its listed as webapp-container. Minitube is not installed. So grep for minitube shows nothing. grep restricted extras shows: ii  ubuntu-restricted-extras                              60                                                  amd64        Commonly used restricted packages for Ubuntu

Comment: @Haifi you should've mentioned the name of the app. Just out of curiosity why are you not using Minitube for Youtube videos? It's basically the most popular Youtube app.

Comment: The app, when opened shows me a youtube page, and in the upper part is a notice i had to update my flash player from adobe, which is nonsense because it is installed properly. If I try to play a video it tells me that it cannot be played because flash is not installed. *rolleyes*

Comment: Umm well... The software center asked me if it should install a youtube app instead of watching youtube in Chrome, so I agreed :) It was not minitube, but it should work nonetheless.

Comment: @Haifi I'm not familiar with the app you're trying to work with as Minitube offers everything you need to watch videos from Youtube, if you need assistance I can guide you how to install working stable version of Minitube.

Comment: Thx, but no need to mate. Just installed minitube and it runs out of the box, just strange that software you get recommended from the software center should not work...

Comment: Some softwares in Ubuntu Software Center not getting updated to newer versions as you can get with help of PPA because in Ubuntu Software Center kept stable/certified versions, but some websites like Youtube sometimes change their code and the app like Minitube becomes unstable and PPA maintainer fix this issue faster. Current stable version of Minitube is `2.1.6-1`

Answer (score 1):

you can search for the " Browser " in the Unity then google this:

https://www.youtube.com/html5

then press "Request HTML5 where possible"

here is the link to the thread:

[Flash not supported on webapps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450663/flash-not-supported-on-webapps/457433#457433?newreg=ff5a42af5056452eaa30f8bf3e19234c)

Try it! I have heard it works but unfo. it does not 4 me :((