# How to get youtube webapp to play videos?

Tags: video, youtube

I am new to Ubuntu and I have installed 14.04.  When I went to YouTube via Firefox it informed me that there was a YouTube app and asked if I wanted to install it.  I said yes, and it installs.  When I try to play videos the app acts as though it is going to open them, but the loading icon pops up and the video never seems to start playing.  If I go to the video in Firefox, the videos do play but I was hoping to use the app to watch the videos and have full access to my account.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

**This is Bug. You should use firefox or chrome.**

[Flash not supported on webapps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450663/flash-not-supported-on-webapps)