# How to add media keys for a player/plugin to the Sound menu in Unity

Tags: 14.04, flash, dbus, totem, indicator-sound

I want to add media keys for Totem and Adobe Flash player to the sound menu in the upper bar of Unity.Is there a way to do this?

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image: Screenshot]

If it is not possible to do it in general for the Adobe Flash Player then I am mainly interested for the Youtube page.

Comment: Which browser are you using to view youtube videos? You may be able to to change the VLC controls to totem's by changing which program is default in the 'Details' settings window.

Comment: Oops!I forgot to mention that. I am using firefox.Actually I am trying to add extra programs to the sound indicator.I am not trying to remove others in favor of totem and flash player

Comment: @underdog012 sound indicator uses MPRIS. So if Firebox supports it, you can control volume through indicator. AFAIK, if you install youtube web app for unity (unity web app services), it works. You may want to see this: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/1IBcyIVs8rA

Comment: @KhurshidAlam OK.I have a few questions. How do I know if firefox supports MPRIS? I googled it and I couldn't find anything. Plus  I noticed something weird. The Webapp for Youtube is unable to play videos. I reinstalled the webapp, I enabled HTML5 in both "Browser" and Youtube Webapp but still nothing.

Comment: @underdog012 The unity webapp ('unity-webapp-youtube' package) is nothing but when you browse youtube it will ask you install a extension. After allowing it, it automatically gets installed & enables MPRIS. Also some videos simply do not (yet) play with HTML5. You need peeper flash plugin. Webapp installing instruction is available [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/unity-webapps-available-in-ubuntu-1210.html). This is old, but still works

Comment: @KhurshidAlam It has unmet dependencies and the website advices the users to remove that ppa because this feature is now available in the official repos. I don't quite get it though. Why the Youtube webapp is nothing?As far as I can recall from an older version of Ubuntu the webapp was capable of playing the videos. Also the flash player is already installed in my system and the option of desktop integration is enabled in firefox.

Comment: For firefox I found this http://askubuntu.com/questions/450663/flash-not-supported-on-webapps. Please read the comments. Now what about Totem.How can I add it to the Sound menu?

Comment: Flash support for containers (for webapps) is available for `14.10`. It will arrive in `14.04` soon. [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-webapps-youtube/+bug/1308842)Totem MPRIS is pre-compiled with it. When you start playing it will appear in sound menu (in 14.04 as well). Also enable `dbus-service from` `edit>plugins`. But you should ask separate question for totem.

Comment: Thank you so much Khurshid Alam! My original question contained both Flash and Totem and I imagined that there will be a general trick which someone can do to add media keys to the sound menu. Anyway thanks again.Can you please write your last comment as an answer?